# SLIM login manager Causes Urxvt window to loose Transparent/Opacity effect

Tags: xorg, x11, gentoo, urxvt

On Gentoo....

This is strange.... when I start X through SLIM I loose the opacity(transparent look) on my urxvt windows. It's only when I start X through SLIM. If I start X with xinit directly, without SLIM, then my `urxvt` windows correctly have the opacity as they should.

The window manager is started the same way regardless with or without slim...through the .xinitrc file:

```
compiz --replace ccp& 
xterm
```

There are no issues with `compiz` ether way...only the transparency with `urxvt`.

The transparency with `urxvt` is set in `.Xdefaults` wtih:

```
urxvt*borderColor: rgba:0000/0000/0000/dddd 
URxvt*background: rgba:0000/0000/0000/dddd
```